# How to selectively delete Android Firebase Notifications (in the System Tray)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive), Firebase for Android Notifications are delivered to the System Tray when the app is in the background.

How to I retrieve all Notifications and selectively delete the ones based on some logic? (Of course, I'll determine the logic, but how do I retrieve them and identify them?)

Is it correct to use NotificationManager to delete notifications in the System Tray?

Any code example would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Using the NotificationManager, AFAIK, is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

we had same problem and we resolved it by not sending notification body.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

As it's mentioned in documentation you only receive the message to method `public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` in your `FirebaseMessagingService`, when there is no notification body. Otherwise it falls to system tray and android handles it.

Although it's not possible to send notification without notification body from console. You have to build your own backend.